# Primefaces and themeroller firefox developer tool

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, primefaces, themeroller

I was able to create my own theme with themeroller and use it in primefaces as explained in the manual.

Then I tried this: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/developertool/
Should this work with primefaces?  It doesn't load any theme settings from the page or change them.  I am using Firefox 4.

Edit - Is this maybe a problem using it with Firefox 4.  I can't get it to work anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. The drag and drop thingy didn't work...

I found the answer in this comment:

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/introducing_the_themeroller_firefox_developer_bookmarklet/#commentNumber10

You must right click the link and add it to your Bookmarks. Then go to the page you want to style and click the bookmark. ThemeRoller window should appear allowing you to play with it.

I'm using it with Firefox 4.